# Custom domain GitHub and HostGator

Tags: domains, nameserver, github, hostgator

I've read all about my theme but just can't get trough!

So, I have a website on GitHub and it is published as `https://namesecondname.github.io/repositoryname/`.  and I bought a domain on HostGator. I've made a CNAME in my gh-pages and the next step was to add namservers in my HostGator domain management. There I need to write nameservers and now I'm stuck! WHAT ARE ACTUALLY NAMESERVERS AT GITHUB?

What should I write there? I tried adding `name.github.io` and I've tried adding this link  `https://namesecondname.github.io/repositoryname/` and tried without http. BUT nothing happens. When I go to the domain I get their webpage that says "You are almost there blablabla" and they remain me I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to change the DNS. If you did that, the CNAME and A records would be pushed to be handled by Github, and that is not how it works.

**Add a CNAME file to your repository in the GitHub account.**

1. Once you log into your GitHub account, click on your repository
   name:
2. Then click on the + sign to add a new file to your repository:
3. Use CNAME for File Name and enter a domain you've purchased in the
   first line of the editing section.
4. Then click on the Commit new file button at the bottom of the page:
5. Select Settings from the right sidebar:
6. In the GitHub Pages section, you should see your domain from the
   CNAME file:

**Back at Hostgator:**

Here you will need to create three records for your domain:

1. A record for @ pointing to 192.30.252.153
2. A record for @ pointing to 192.30.252.154
3. CNAME record for www pointing to your username.github.io (the
   username should be replaced with your actual GitHub account
   username):

Comment: I get `A zone name must be a domain name, and can include a period at the end.` this error on `Name` when I try to write @ in `Name` field

Comment: if `@` doesn't work, try leaving the name field blank.  `@` represents the "domain apex" meaning "no sub-domain".  `@` is used in DNS zone files, but DNS web interfaces often expect you to leave the name blank for domain apex records.